# Caching all processes for specific windows user

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, cache

I am currently sharing a laptop with another person, and I'd like to cache all of their processes while I'm logged in to my account.  I would also like to have separate cache for both me and the other person. I run Windows 7 Home Premium with Sp1.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: What you want isn't possible.

Comment: Then this should be an answer, no? :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cache processes?  Are you talking about having those processes moved out of RAM to the pagefile, or?

Comment: Yes. And creating two seperate page files: one for each user.

Comment: I have another question I forgot to mention, but I think the answer is yes: Does more data in page files decrease battery life faster? If so, then is it possible to save the processes to my hard drive in more of a permanent manor (like regular files) instead a temporary one?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, you can set up a hardware profile for each user.  You may still be able to do that in Windows 7, but I haven't the time to test this assumption.  If it is possible, then if you have multiple drives, for the second user put his entire page file in the separate drive.  If you don't have a second hard drive, then just create an empty folder and use dos commands to set it up to simulate a drive (basically, you'll be assigning a drive letter to  a folder)  and see if you can place the second user's page file to occupy this false drive.  best of luck.

Comment: So you're just speculating on a Win 7 answer?  How many laptops have multiple drives?  How would someone go about placing a page file in that location?  This answer doesn't address what was asked in the question.